# Swift 4 : add subviews in UIimage view (PanGestureRecognizer)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uipangesturerecognizer

How can I add subviews in UIImageView in move (PanGestureRecognizer)?

My code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!

@objc func PanAction(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let imageViewPoint:CGPoint = sender.location(in: img)

    var imx:UIImageView?
    imx =  UIImageView.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "small"))
    img.addSubview(imx!)
    imx!.frame.origin = imageViewPoint
}
```

The code works poorly, see the image.

-- right image my code  (✗)

-- I need the result like a left image  (✓)

[image]

Comment: I think `UIPanGesture ` won't help you to achieve this. You should go for **free hand drawing**  [refer this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1934-how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-app-with-uikit-and-swift)

Comment: Small circle is a png image and I want to use another image

Comment: Where is your sender.state? Also you should draw not add sub views. Adding views is too slow

Comment: Thank you for reply , any idea to draw using png image as brush